# How to install bzlib.h package without root privilege / yum command to install a software in home directory on remote server

Tags: linux, installation, package-management, packages, libraries

I am trying to install a package that includes "bzlib.h" so that I am able to install the "AmberTools14"/"Amber14" software in my home directory on a remote server, but since I don't have root access, I cannot use the command `yum install bzip2-devel-1.0.5-7.el6_0.x86_64` to install this package. What is the easiest way for me to install this package and have it accessible when I try to compile/install Amber14 using intel compilers?

I'm not very familiar with how compiling software works or what packages are for in general so I'm not sure if it's possible or makes sense for me to just download the rpm file from this link (https://centos.pkgs.org/6/centos-x86_64/bzip2-devel-1.0.5-7.el6_0.x86_64.rpm.html) and then using the WinSCP program on Windows, I could transfer it over into my home directory on the remote server, install the rpm file somehow so that the "bzlib.h" file gets installed, and then when I'm compiling/installing Amber14, I could give the path of where bzlib.h was installed in my home directory so that it will be able to find it? Does that make sense at all? And if so, how would I install the rpm file once I've moved it with WinSCP onto the remote server?

I ran some commands to find out some info about the system in case this is helpful?

Command: `uname -s`
Output: Linux
Command: `uname -r`
Output: 2.6.32-696.23.1.el6.centos.plus.x86_64
Command: `uname -v`
Output: #1 SMP Wed Mar 14 11:51:06 UTC 2018
Command: `uname -m`
Output: x86_64
Command: `uname -p`
Output: x86_64
Command: `uname -i`
Output: x86_64
Command: `uname -o`
Output: GNU/Linux

Command: `gcc --version`
Output: gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat
4.4.7-18) Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc. This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Command: `icc --version`
Output: icc (ICC) 16.0.2 20160204 Copyright (C) 1985-2016 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.

The reason why I want to try to install the "bzlib.h" package is because I've tried to install AmberTools14/Amber14 according to the instructions at this link (http://jswails.wikidot.com/installing-amber14-and-ambertools14) except I used the command `./configure intel` instead of `./configure gnu`, but I received the error below:

> Checking for libbz2: testp.c(2): catastrophic error: cannot open
>   source file "bzlib.h"
>    #include "bzlib.h"
>     ^
>   compilation aborted for testp.c (code 4)
>   ./configure2: line 2079: ./testp: No such file or directory
>   Not found.

So I think my installation of the Amber14 software ended up having some problems, and maybe the missing bzlib.h might be part of the reason why I can't use parts of the software.

Also, since I think I'm using Centos 6, from this link with instructions for which packages I need to install Amber (http://ambermd.org/Installation.php), I was wondering if someone could give me some advice on how I could follow the instructions below to install all of these package without root access or using "yum".

> CentOS 6 Installation of Amber on a CentOS 6 Linux node is a little
>   tricky since the default GNU compiler is now too old to compile the
>   source code. The recommended procedure is to install a more recent
>   version using the Developer Toolset software collection (devtoolset).
>
> yum -y install tcsh make \
>                  which flex bison patch bc \
>                  libXt-devel libXext-devel \
>                  perl util-linux wget bzip2 \
>                  bzip2-devel zlib-devel
>
> # update to a newer gcc yum -y install centos-release-scl yum -y install devtoolset-8 then, in your terminal, access the newer GNU
>   compiler using:
>
> source /opt/rh/devtoolset-8/enable

I saw a comment at this link (https://askubuntu.com/questions/339/how-can-i-install-a-package-without-root-access) about installing a program called "JuJu" and maybe this might help me install all the packages I need, but I'm very confused to how this works and how to install this since I still don't really understand the meaning of the terms kernel/distribution/package/library/compiler/rpm/dependencies/repository/environment and how they relate exactly, so if someone could explain this, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Also, I'm not really sure of the difference between compiling and installing a software, and the difference between a package and a library, if anyone has a basic explanation for that, I'd appreciate it! I've been googling a lot of things but since I have no computer science or IT background, most of the explanations I find are too complicated for me to understand without even more googling and reading for hours.

Comment: `bzlib.h` is a C header, i.e. a text file. Unpack http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.10/os/x86_64/Packages/bzip2-devel-1.0.5-7.el6_0.x86_64.rpm ... and try this : Copy the header bzlib.h to `amber14/AmberTools/src/include/` ....Note : I don't see any options for CFLAGS : `$ ./configure --full-help`